# Can you sort the parameter dropdown list by a field not in the parameter list?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have an SSRS report with a parameter list.  The data source is a dataset model, so no SQL with an  order by in this scenario.  The list is sorted in alphabetical order but I want it to be sorted in another order, defined by another field in the model.  Is there a way to get the parameter dropdown values to be sorted by this other field that is not to be displayed in the dropdown?

Comment: What is your "dataset model". Just a shared dataset or a PowerBI model? Either way, can you create a column for your parameter values something like "SortValue|ActualValue" use this to sort and then strip out the bit before the `|` (in this example) when the parameter value gets passed to the main query?

Comment: @AlanSchofield.  The model is a PBI datset (i.e, a .pbix file that is a semantic layer on top of the dbase) pblishd to the cloud. I think I follow your idea; i.e, in the dtaset query where I define the prmters, filters, fields, query, I would use a formula in the parm part that strips off the text before the | symbol. This should make the dropdwn parm work and displaying the value on the rpt.  But then I need to pass the parm value selected to a drill through rpt. I believe this may be pssble using the 'ReportItems' fnction, which passes the value as it appears on the rpt, not the prm value.

Comment: @AlanSchofield.   Your suggestion worked!